# Oracle Data Archiving & Purging

Tags: oracle

Can anyone please tell me what tech should i use for archiving & purging the historic data.

Comment: That's a very broad question.  Can you be a bit more specific about the requirements?  Archiving implies that you may want to restore the data again at some point in the future.  Purging implies that you just want to get rid of it.  Are there DATE columns that identify what data is "historic"?  Are you getting rid of everything older than a certain date?  Or are you doing something more selective?  Are you building a system and thinking about data lifecycle management?  Or are you trying to add data lifecycle management to an existing application?

Comment: Thnx Justin for you quick response.
Currently we are in 3rd year having 800 GB data in our production database.
requirement is to archive all the data to a seprate structure & keep only 1 year data in production.
Archiving data we want to keep only for reference.
Yes we have date columns & relationship within object which will identify the data as historic.

Answer (score 4):

As Justin said in his comment this is a broad question.  A broad answer is to use [Oracle Partitioning](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/partitioning/index.htm).  In general this will allow you to treat subsets of data with DDL (truncating, moving, or dropping partitions) instead of more resource-intensive DML.

Comment: Partitioning will also allow you to set different physical attributes for the archived partitions.  For example, if you rarely update the archived data you can set PCTFREE to 0 instead of the default of 10, and save 10% on space.  And you might want to consider a larger block size for the archived partitions (this could help with compression, and maybe slightly reduce the amount of overhead).

Answer (score 0):

As part of the solution you might want to consider [table compression](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#sthref733).  It can potentially save a lot of space.